# Повесить на <option> обработчик выбранного варианта

Tags: javascript, html, css3, html5

Суть задачи в том что нужно от выбранного варианта открыть нужную страничку. Есть в корне сайта (допустим) var1.html, var2.html, var3.html Собсно исходя из того что пользователь выбрал в `option` вариант 1 - открыть var1.html , соответственно так же с 2 и 3 вариантом. Не могу понять как правильно написать на js такую конструкцию которая проверит какой `option` сейчас выбран и соответственно его value открыть нужную страничку.

```js
function Check_Var(){
    var sel_option = document.getElementByTagName("option");

    if (sel_option.value == "var1") {
       // открыть нужную страницу 
    }
}
```

```css
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#main{
 width: 400px;
 height: 270px;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 margin:  0 auto;
 margin-top: 70px;
}

.avt{
 border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.margin-top{
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.avt_form button{
 margin-top: 20px;
 width: 80px;
}

.avt_form button a{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#sel{
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <title>Авторизация</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="main">
  <div class="avt"><center><h1>Авторизация</h1></center></div>
  <div class="avt_form">
   <center>
    <p class="margin-top">Введите имя и фамилию:</p>
    <input type="text" name=""><br/>
    <select name="vars" id="sel">
     <option selected value="var1">Вариант 1</option>
      <option value="var2">Вариант 2</option>
      <option value="var3">Вариант 3</option>
   </select>
   <br/>
    <button> <a href="ask.html" onclick="Check_Var()">Далее</a></button>
   </center>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <a href> в баттоне написан сейчас просто для затычки

Comment: написал проверку какой value сейчас выбран а в итоге получил underfined 
`var sel_option = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
    alert('Выбрана опция '+sel_option.value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так пойдет?

```js
function changeLink(s){
    document.querySelector('#btn')
            .setAttribute('href', s.options[s.selectedIndex].value)
}
```

```html
<select name="vars" id="sel" onchange="changeLink(this)">
  <option value="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" selected>https://ru.stackoverflow.com</option>
  <option value="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help">https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help</option>
  <option value="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour">https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour</option>
</select>
<br/>
<a id="btn" href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"><button>go</button></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема в том, что вы зачем-то пытаетесь ковыряться в `option'ах`, в то время как вам нужно взять значение `value` у элемента `select`, в котором эти `option'ы` находятся. Это же основы HTML.

В ваше примере:

```
<select name="vars" id="sel">
    <option selected value="var1">Вариант 1</option>
    <option value="var2">Вариант 2</option>
    <option value="var3">Вариант 3</option>
</select>
```

`value` у `option'ов` - не значения, а всего лишь атрибуты. Как значения они передаются `select'у`, вот к нему и нужно обращаться:

```
document.getElementById("sel").value
```

Если у вас стоит извращенная задача обращаться именно к `option'ам`, то это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("option")[i].getAttribute("value");
```

но тут будут трудности: во-первых, придется знать, какой именно `option` из `select'а` был выбран (чтобы обратиться к нему по индексу `i`), а во-вторых вам понадобится как-то определить сам факт выбора пользователем именно этого `option'а`, что будет нетривиальной задачей. *Когда вы прокачаетесь настолько, что сможете решить ее, напишите, и я вам расскажу об атрибуте `multiple` у элемента `select`, вот тогда повеселимся ;)*

П.С. конструкция из комментария:

```
var sel_option = document.getElementsByTagName("option"); 
alert('Выбрана опция '+sel_option.value);
```

- бред. 'sel_option' - это вообще-то массив, у которого свойства `value` нет.

Comment: окей, возьму к сведению, спасибо)